# Clicking of InkWell or GestureDector in Flutter and in iOS not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I encountering a weird problem in the iOS simulator and specifically in iPhone 12 pro max simulator. [You can get the video from this link](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1pHP3E2muO8_4sB85i33rpjZOjB0WjaRv)

Please have a look at this video as it works well in the iPhone 8 but not in the iPhone 12 max pro but I would say that it doesn't work in iPhone 11 as well. It works fine on Android devices.

Following is the code that I am using:

```
// SizedBox(
   //   height: sizedHeight,
   // ),
 Hero(
    tag: 'mannafy_logo',
    child: Material(
             child: GestureDetector(
                     child: Image.asset(
                               "assets/images/mannafy_logo.png",
                               width: 125,
                               fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                      onTap: () async {
                                    const url = 'https://www.mannafy.com';
                                    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                                      await launch(url);
                                    } else {
                                      throw 'Could not launch $url';
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Now here comes the weirdest part that if you un-comment the SizedBox Code so it starts to work fine but I don't want to add space above that image.

Please help to solve this issue.

THANKS

Comment: Try to wrap it into `SafeArea`, maybe it helps.

Comment: I have wrapped in SafeArea but still getting the space above my image.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution that I was using SafeArea before the MaterialApp and before Scaffold as well, so what I did was I removed all SafeArea's and used only once inside Scaffold.

It worked.

Comment: I was trying to show tooltips after an onTap on an icon layered on a Flutter map (flutter_map package) and could not get the tooltips to show on iOS actual devices until I removed the SafeArea.